# How to do mac spoofing on Linux Mint 17?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-mint, ethernet, pppd

How to do mac spoofing on Linux Mint 17?
Through `macchanger -a` I've tried to changemy mac address but new mac id doesn't authenticates successfully. `pppd` gives successful authentication message only when it connects to specific mac id.
How can I assign that specific mac address in configuration file to make it successful authentications

Answer (score 3):

You can check if your MAC address really changed by using `ifconfig` and look the `HWAddr` value behind the appropriate device name.

What has worked for me on Mint, without any additional programs to install is using ifconfig:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo ifconfig eth0 hw ether 00:01:02:03:04:05
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

or in  more permanent fashion by adding the line:

```
hwaddress ether 00:01:02:03:04:05
```

in `/etc/network/interfaces`, so that this MAC is set on bootup.

Comment: The temporary solution works well for me, the permanent has no effect after reboot. Mint Cinnamon 17.3